# How to get block comments in user defined language to work properly in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am building a definition for a propriatery language that uses c style comment blocks.

I have set the following:

Comment open: /* 
Comment close: */ 
Treat keywords as symbols (in Comment Block frame): Checked

I do not have `*` or `/` set as activated operators.

This results in the following formatting: 
(I've commented the comments to show if the comments were treated as comments by the commenting engine of notepad++)

```
/*comment*/   //comment
code          //comment (but should be code)
/* comment */ //comment
code          //code
/**/code/**/  //comment (but should be code)
code          //comment (but should be code)
/*comment     //comment
comment       //comment
comment*/     //comment
code          //code
/*            //comment
comment       //comment
*/            //comment
```

If I uncheck Treat keywords as symbols I get this:

```
/*comment*/   //code (but should be comment)
code          //code
/* comment */ //comment
code          //code
/**/code/**/  //code (both /**/ show as code as well)
code          //code
/*comment     //code (but should be comment)
comment       //code (but should be comment)
comment*/     //code (but should be comment)
code          //code
/*            //comment
comment       //comment
*/            //comment
```

I have also tried every commbination of Treat keywords as symbols and adding `*` and `/` to the operator list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works correctly (N++ 6.5.5), please see the result.

Highlighted by yellow is the only thing I touched after creating new language:

[image]

Comment folding works too, use the checkbox visible on the screenshot.

Comment: It looks like it was a bug in an old version of N++.  It works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have unix or mixed style line endings in your text file. You need to change this to windows style line endings:

> **In Notepad++ menu:** Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows Format

Comment: Do I understand that correctly that you are saying that line endings settings interfere with block comment syntax recognition?